# How to add ListAdapter in RemoteViews in Android Widget

Tags: android

Does anyone know how to implement dynamic ListAdapter in RemoteViews for Widgets ? or even is it possible ?

```
private static final String[] lists={"abc", "def", "ghi",
                                "jkl", "mno", "pqr",
                                "stu", "vwx", "xyz"};


@Override
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
RemoteViews row=new RemoteViews(ctxt.getPackageName(), R.layout.row);

row.setTextViewText(android.R.id.text1, lists[position]);

Intent i=new Intent();
Bundle extras=new Bundle();

extras.putString(WidgetProvider.EXTRA_WORD, lists[position]);
i.putExtras(extras);
row.setOnClickFillInIntent(android.R.id.text1, i);

return(row);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

...yes, we (s)can! See [allowed classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124321/can-we-add-a-listview-to-a-remoteview-in-android). But I don't now how. I'm also interrested in a code-snipplet.