# Can we add a ListView to a RemoteView in android?

Tags: android, listview, remoteview

Is it possible to add a ListView to a RemoteView in android? By ListView I don't mean just a list of items,I need a list with checkboxes, so I want to actually use a ListView and add items to it by using an adapter.Is that possible within a RemoteView? Or is adding strings from an array the only way to do it? If it is possible to add a ListView within a RemoteView, please mention the steps to be followed. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ListView` is one of the [allowed classes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout) for `RemoteView`, but subclasses are not permitted so `CheckBox` is unavailable.